# Tips for better image quality (Video Editing)

Tags: image, video-sequence-editor, video

So I'm trying to edit a video with Blender and I wanted to add images to it. The images that I'm using are created using GIMP. The problem I'm having is that when I add an image to the VSE, it appears on the video but the quality isn't good compared to the original image, which has high quality. Any tips on what I can do to improve it's quality in the video? [image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 100% better quality...? But the VSE preview is built for speed. The output quality is going to be based on the resolution of the video and the chosen codec, not the original image

Comment: @GiantCowFilms Oops sorry about that. I didn't make it clear. Uhm what I meant to say was that the quality of the original image doesn't appear the same when I add it to the video. But thanks for your answer. I kinda get it now. :)

Comment: @GiantCowFilms Oh gosh. I'm such a noob. I've finally figured it out. Everything's great (including images) after my video finished rendering. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blender uses a fast form of interpolation in the VSE preview, which can give a jagged result.

You don't really have to worry as this won't be in the final render, but it should also go away when you view the preview at `1:1` resolution so nothing needs to be interpolated. You can jump to `1:1` zoom by pressing <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> in the preview.

Not `1:1`:

[image]

`1:1`:

[image]

Comment: I figured it out a few minutes ago because of another member but thanks so much for the explanation! :D

Comment: That explains why my images were appearing like the 1st picture here, even the images that I created with Inkscape. -.-