# F12 render appears pixelated

Tags: rendering, image

I press F12 to render the camera view, but I just get a pixelish version of the render.

[image]

Can somebody tell me how to change that?
I have already changed the object's "Render" Resolution to 100%.

Well, I have something to report now: When I use the middle mouse button to scroll out a little, the render appears a little smaller (seemingly at 100%), and it looks the way I expected. However, I wonder why that is that the render appears at like 125% for me instead of 100%.

Comment: Blender uses a very fast nearest interpolation, which sometimes looks pixelated when not viewed at 1:1. Press 1 on the numpad while viewing the render to view it at 1:1. This is the same thing which causes this in the VSE, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/22837/599

Comment: @gandalf3 I have changed my question and added that if I scroll out a little, it looks fine. Is your comment still valid then?

Comment: @JohannHesters Yep, my comment is saying that it looks fine at 100% (which is what it seems you discovered simultaneously)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an artifact of the [interpolation method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest-neighbor_interpolation) blender uses to display images. Image viewers which use other interpolation methods should display the image just fine.

The artifacts should disappear if you view the image at 100% (<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>), so that no interpolation is needed.